# How to know if a file system is read only (.NET Standard)?

Tags: c#, io, .net-standard

I have a function that reads a file and if it doesn't exist it creates and fills it. However this is in a .NET Standard Library and is called from an AWS Lambda function which gives back the following error:

> "Read-only file system"

How can I determine that the file system is read only in code so I can skip the file creation and when its the case?

EDIT: My question is different than [Is there a way to check if a file is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use). That question is asking about trying to read a file before it is saved. I am asking how to know if the file system wouldn't allow me to save a file (due to restrictions in the file system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, for nearly *everything* to do with file systems, the trick is to remember they are **volatile,** and therefore the answer is to just `try` whatever you want to do and handle the exception if it fails.

To understand what I mean by, "volatile", let's say you have some magic `Path.IsReadOnlyFileSystem()` method that does exactly what you want. So you want to run some code like this:

```
if (!Path.IsReadOnlyFileSystem(fileIWantToCreate))
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileIWantToCreate))
    {
        //fill file here
    }
}
```

But then something happens in your AWS cloud forcing the service to go into read-only mode. And it happens right here:

```
if (!Path.IsReadOnlyFileSystem(fileIWantToCreate))
{
    /* <==== AWS goes read-only here ====> */
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileIWantToCreate))
```

Your magic method did it's job perfectly. At the moment you called the method, the file system still allowed writes. Unfortunately, a volatile file system means you can't trust operations from one moment to the next (and a non-volatile file system wouldn't be much good to you for saving data). So you might be tempted to go for a pattern like this:

```
try 
{
    if (!Path.IsReadOnlyFileSystem(fileIWantToCreate))
    {
        using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileIWantToCreate))
        {
            //fill file here
        }
    }
}
catch(  )
{
    // handle the exception here
}
```

And now it's clear *you have to handle the exception anyway.* The `if()` condition doesn't really gain anything in terms of actual functionality. All it really does is add complexity to your code.

Even so, there's a tendency to believe keeping the `if()` condition gains a performance benefit by saving an exception handler and saving a disk access. ***This belief is flawed.***

The `if()` condition actually **adds** disk access when it checks the file system status. Moreover, this cost is added on *every* execution. Keeping the `if()` condition does save the exception handler, but only on occasions where the initial access fails. Admittedly, unrolling the stack to handle an exception is among the most expensive operations you can do in all of computer science. This is the "why" behind the "don't use exceptions for normal control flow" mantra. However, disk access is one of the few things that is *far and away worse* for performance.

In summary, we have an exception handler stack unwind sometimes vs an extra disk access every time. From a performance standpoint it's clear you're better off without the `if()` condition at all. We don't need the `if()` condition for correctness reasons, and we don't want it for performance reasons.... remind me again why we have it? The better pattern skips that block completely, like this:

```
try
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileIWantToCreate))
    {
        //fill file here
    }
}
catch( )
{
    // handle the exception here
}
```

Thus the magic `IsReadOnlyFileSystem()` method is not needed or even helpful.

This isn't to say that method doesn't exist (I don't think it's part of .Net Standard, but depending on your platform there's likely a lower-level construct you can call into). It's just that it's not a particularly good idea.

Comment: My test shows that `try { throw new Exception(); } catch { }` is much slower than creating a file.